# Foreach loop returning one letter only

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning PHP basics and there is a problem I cannot quite understand.

I am trying to fetch some articles

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, 'SELECT id, title, url FROM articles');
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $articles[] = $row['title'];
}
```

and I want to output the title

```
foreach ($articles as $a) {
    echo $a['title'];
}
```

Actually it is just outputting the first letter of the titles. My titles are "test" and "another test" and I just see "t" and "a" as an output.

What's wrong?

Comment: Just do `foreach ($articles as $a) {echo $a;}`.

Comment: You have no `title` key in `$articles` Do `var_dump` or `print_r` to see the contents of your array.

Comment: You already do `$articles[] = $row['title'];` so `$a['title']` is the equivalent of `$row['title']['title']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are storing the value of the element 'title' in a new array. You could do 2 things:

- Just print `$a`
- Store `$row` in a new array

That means in your while loop, replace:

```
$articles[] = $row['title'];
```

By

```
$articles[] = $row;
```

Answer (score 1):

> After first loop just use

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($articles);
echo "</pre>";
```

> and then use

```
foreach($articles as $a) {
    echo $a;
}
```